# Why I get different date format for same SQL run on linked MySQL server and Query Designer of BIDS

Tags: mysql, date, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, bids

I have created a linked MySQL server on MS SQL Server Management Studio.
When I run following SQL from Management Studio it gives date format same as in the MySQL table:

```
SELECT
*
FROM OPENQUERY (
    LinkedServerName,
    'select distinct date from DatabaseName.Tablename order by date desc limit 10;'
);
```

Result is:

```
date
2017-06-28
2017-06-27
2017-06-26
2017-06-25
2017-06-24
2017-06-23
2017-06-22
2017-06-21
2017-06-20
2017-06-19
```

This is consistent with definition of date field in MySQL table, which is:
[image]

But when I run same SQL from Query Designer of Business Intelligence Development Studio I get date field in different format.

The result of same SQL from BIDS is:

[image]

Is there a way I can modify my SQL so result in BIDS shows date format as yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: To prevent this you can try `CAST(TheDateSet USING DATE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was little impatient! I was able to get it working using:

```
SELECT
*
FROM OPENQUERY (
    LinkedServerName,
    'select distinct DATE_FORMAT(date, ''%Y-%m-%d'') from DatabaseName.Tablename order by date desc limit 10;'
);
```

I wanted to keep the field in date format and hence didn't want to change it as varchar. The above approach serves that as well.